# Server refused our key, set authorized_keys perrmissions to 777

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, public-key-encryption

I was copying some files from my home directory on my ec2 instance, and in a fit of laziness, I ran the command sudo chmod 777 /home/ec2-user/*.  I guess this made my .ssh folder and possibly the authorized_keys have 777 privileges as well.  Well it turns out that if authorized_keys is set to 777, you cannot SSH into the box with those keys (since another user could have updated it).

My question is, how can I fix this and log into my box again?  This is an ec2 instance, so I have to ssh in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Change permissions you'll need to access the files that are inside the Instance.

Since you can't ssh in the Instance you'll need to do the following things:

1. Schedule a downtime for your application, because you'll need to stop the instance.
2. Back-up everything inside the Instance Store(ephemeral volumes).
3. Stop the instance.
4. Detach the Volume from the EC2 instance in question.
5. Attach the Volume to another working EC2 instance.
6. Make the `chmod` changes to your .ssh directory and it's files.
7. Detach the volume.
8. Attach to the EC2 instance in question.
9. Start the EC2 Instance.
10. Try Connecting to the EC2 instance.

Please note that if you don't have Elastic IP configured for the Instance, the IP address will change.

For more information about attaching volume to EC2 instance refer to this [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html).

Comment: My instance reboots when i click the Volumes tab to detach the volume. do you know why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290095/how-to-change-permission-of-a-file-on-the-amazon-remote-instance-when-ssh-doesn?noredirect=1#comment63998071_38290095

Comment: Because logically, you're removing Storage device from a running machine.

Comment: my but why my instance keeps on restarting after stopping

Answer (score 1):

To keep the downtime minimum, take the image of instance (in no-reboot mode) and create a new machine with this image and the key that you had previously specified.
AWS, while creating the new box, puts the keys with proper permissions.

Note that private and public IPs will change, use elastic IP if you don't want IP change then use elastic IP.

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me... The same issue remained, and it looks like the key was not replaced... As a note I used the same private key as I used for the old instance, so I don't know if that affected it.